# Python: Permission denied error while setting up archive database

Tags: linux, python-3.x, postgresql, wal-e

I was setting up scheduled backup of my postgresql database on my server using [wal-e](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e). I was following this [link](https://edwardsamuel.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/set-up-scheduled-postgresql-backup-to-aws-s3-using-wal-e/). (Just have a look at the article from Step 3)
When I execute the below command after initial setup .
 `sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.

I get following error:-

```
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3-1.24.1.dist-info'
```

Please help

Comment: Does the file exist? Dou you have read permissions?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, sudo have read permissions.

Comment: Knowing little about Python, I'd probably use `strace` to find out more about what causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same issue. Your postgres user is not able to access the distribution packages.

Try running the below command. It should resolve the issue.

```
chmod a+xr -R /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/*
```